# Vich Uploader Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not allowed

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

Well. I'm trying to implement vich uploader bundle due to make user profile photo. I've installed it, made `User` entity with link to `UserPhoto` entity (one to one relation). But I have exception when trying to upload user photo (`Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not allowed`).

Here it is my `UserPhoto` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserPhotoRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class UserPhoto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="user_photo", fileNameProperty="photoName", size="photoSize")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    private $photoFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $photoName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $photoSize;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $photoFile
     */
    public function setPhotoFile(?File $photoFile = null): self
    {
        $this->photoFile = $photoFile;

        if (null !== $photoFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhotoFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->photoFile;
    }

    public function setPhotoName(?string $photoName): self
    {
        $this->photoName = $photoName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhotoName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photoName;
    }

    public function setPhotoSize(?int $photoSize): self
    {
        $this->photoSize = $photoSize;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhotoSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->photoSize;
    }

    ///** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    //public function serialize()
    //{
    //    return serialize(array(
    //        $this->id,
    //        $this->photoName,
    //        $this->photoSize,
    //        $this->updatedAt,
    //    ));
    //}
    //
    ///** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    //public function unserialize($serialized)
    //{
    //    list (
    //        $this->id,
    //        $this->photoName,
    //        $this->photoSize,
    //        $this->updatedAt,
    //    ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
    //}
}
```

My User class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="user.exist")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * 
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "user.email.incorrect"
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $patronymic;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number", nullable=true)
     * @AssertPhoneNumber(defaultRegion="RU")
     * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="mobile")
     */
    private $phoneNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isEmailConfirmed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $emailConfirmationToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Notification", mappedBy="user")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"time" = "DESC"})
     */
    private $notifications;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserPhoto", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $photo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notifications = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPatronymic(): ?string
    {
        return $this->patronymic;
    }

    public function setPatronymic(?string $patronymic): self
    {
        $this->patronymic = $patronymic;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber): self
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsEmailConfirmed(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isEmailConfirmed;
    }

    public function setIsEmailConfirmed(bool $isEmailConfirmed): self
    {
        $this->isEmailConfirmed = $isEmailConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmailConfirmationToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->emailConfirmationToken;
    }

    public function setEmailConfirmationToken(?string $emailConfirmationToken): self
    {
        $this->emailConfirmationToken = $emailConfirmationToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Notification[]
     */
    public function getNotifications(): Collection
    {
        return $this->notifications;
    }

    public function addNotification(Notification $notification): self
    {
        if (!$this->notifications->contains($notification)) {
            $this->notifications[] = $notification;
            $notification->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeNotification(Notification $notification): self
    {
        if ($this->notifications->contains($notification)) {
            $this->notifications->removeElement($notification);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($notification->getUser() === $this) {
                $notification->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAtValue()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUpdatedAtValue(){
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getPhoto(): ?UserPhoto
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    public function setPhoto(?UserPhoto $photo): self
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My UserPhoto Form type

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\UserPhoto;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class UserPhotoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('photoFile', VichImageType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => false,
            'imagine_pattern' => 'squared_thumbnail',
            'label' => false,
            'download_label' => false,
            'image_uri' => false,
            'download_uri' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => UserPhoto::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My User profile FormType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use App\Form\CustomPhoneNumberType as PhoneNumberType;
use App\Form\UserPhotoType;

class UserProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('surname')
            ->add('patronymic')
            ->add('photo', UserPhotoType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('phoneNumber', PhoneNumberType::class,
                array('widget' => PhoneNumberType::WIDGET_COUNTRY_CHOICE, 
                'country_choices' => array('RU', 'JE', 'FR', 'US'), 
                'preferred_country_choices' => array('RU', 'US'),
                'translation_domain' => false,
                'required'    => false,
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I was trying to solve this problem myself for a couple of hours but with no luck, that's why I hope somebody can help me. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is that the same Entity used for user authentication? If so I believe you would need to add the `serialize`, `unserialize` methods to the User entity, omitting the photo and other unnecessary properties. This is due to Symfony [serializing the User object for the session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session).

Comment: Well. I have added this to my user
```
 /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }
    
    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
    }
```
And it seems like it's working now.

Comment: It doesn't upload image (don't know why), but at least there is no exception now

Comment: I don't know why but i solved this problem without using serialize, unserialize methods in User entity but by using it in UserPhoto like you did.
Have you tried to manually set updatedAt UsePhoto property in your controller ?

Comment: Another question :

- Have you implemented \Serializable before using serialize, unserialize methods in your UserPhoto Entity ? 
Example : class UserPhoto implements \Serializable {}

Comment: I didn't try to set updated at in controller. What do you mean? I'm trying to use a form, which I suppose will do it itself

Comment: yes. I've implemented \Serializable